# Download an app from the app store, without the UI

Tags: jailbreak

I'm working on a tweak that needs to download and install an app from the App Store (given a bundle id or some kind of other identifier), but doing so without using the App Store app (e.g., to allow the user to remotely instal an app on the device, without going through the App Store UI).

(I'll pause here to point that obviously this has nothing to do with piracy, as I want the app to be downloaded through the user's account in the store, and in any case I'm only targeting free apps at the moment).

I went through iOS 7 private framework headers and couldn't find a way to fit in and to tell the device to install an app with a given identifier. I've also looked for similar tweaks to have a look at their source, but the only one I could find was 'Auto App Updater', and its code isn't public.

I would greatly appreciate your help in coming up with a code that does that, or an open-source tweak that utilises a similar function.

Thanks a lot!
Dan

Comment: Look at the headers for the App Store app on the device. Those will probably be more helpful. iTunesStoreUI.framework also looks promising.